# How do I display MongoDB array values as fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with nested arrays in them as below

```
appname: "app1"
applimit:  "24"
company:  "xyz"
members: Array
 0: Object
    hostname: "host1"
    port: 12345
    build: Object
       version: "123.1"
       buildinfo: Array
          0: enterprise
```

I need to extract  name, age, company, hostname, port and buildinfo with a match condition and export to a spreadsheet and have been tooling around aggregation pipelines but what's happening is that the output I get is that the members array values are all clubbed together in JSON. Ideally I'd like to get these values as field names. Is that even possible?

```
db.collection.aggregate ([{
    $match: {
    company: "xyz"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    appname: 1,
    applimit: 1,
    company: 1,
    members: 1
    }
}, { 
    $sort: 
    {_id: -1}
    }])
```

Comment: Better add example document in json and expected result so we can help you ...